# Two users with different permissions on same directory

Tags: permissions, files, users, group

Is it possible to give two users different permissions on the same directory? I want to use it for ftp: userFull gets R+W and userLim gets only Read, depending on who logs on. Im getting stuck on the ownership versus group rights... (I use CentOS+Directadmin and Proftpd)

So the following is what I want if it's possible at all:

```
/home/myDir  -  userFull  -  read & write
/home/myDir  -  userLim  -  read only
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, by using ACL - Access Control Lists. (if not avail, install via `yum install acl`)

Before you start setting ACL, you initially need to enable ACL support for filesystem, for doing it manually use:

```
mount -o remount,acl $filesystem
```

But you need to enter this command every time you boot the system. To avoid this, you can enable acl when the filesystem is mounted, by using [fstab](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab).

Eg. `/etc/fstab` (for your home directory), if you are using ext4 file system:

```
LABEL=/home        /home         ext4           defaults,acl          1 2
```

For more information go to [redhat documentation link](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-acls.html).

By `setfacl` you can assign permission like::

```
setfacl -m u:Full:rwx /home/myDir
setfacl -m u:Lim:rx /home/myDir
```

After that by `getfacl`, you can view the permissions:

```
getfacl /home/myDir
```

For more info, please visit [CentOS documentation page](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-acls-setting.html).

Comment: ok, i've installed setfacl via ``yum install acl`` and used your example. When I do getfacl the permissions are correct, but I still cannot connect with the readonly user (I get a 530 error)

Comment: for directory you also need to have execute permissions (x). Try: `setfacl -m u:Lim:rx /home/myDir`

Comment: @Tejax yep discovered that, thanks! I adjusted  that in your opening post i accepted your answer.

Another question/problem now: when I upload files with userFull and I want to view them with userLim, it doesn't allow that, you know why?

Comment: is this in the same directory (myDir)?

Comment: @Christopher, yes, I forgot to mention about this, I have edited my answer accordingly